# NETLOGO: Distribution of variable on my-links

Tags: variables, sum, netlogo

I have network with number of nodes connected with links. I need to set variable (lets call it "trust") to links so that sum of variables from links from one agent to others makes 100. Example: Agent have 3 links to another agents. Their variables are "34 13 53" or "23 61 16" or " 37 16 47". Sum is always 100. Hope it makes sense. Is there some easy way to do it netlogo?

Answer (score 1):

Just give them the values then normalise. Something like (not tested) `ask agents [ ask my-links [ set trust [ 100 * trust / sum [ trust ] of my-links ] ]`

The problem you are going to have is that the value will need to be different each way. For example, if A and B have a link between them, then trust might need to be 25 at A's end (because the other links total 75) and 50 at B's end. So you actually need the link to have two values - how much A trusts B and how much B trusts A.